# how to replace text from a string with an include file in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to know how to replace some text in php string with like an include or something.

here is my example string:  I have a string "bla bla bla bla {{ module:projects,id=1 }} bla bla bla bla"

I want to find {{ module:projects,id=1 }} and make it include('projects.php?id=1'); right where it is in the string.

how would i pull this off?

An alternative if i could do this but i cant get it to execute the php from the string would be "bla bla bla  bla bla bla"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with preg_replace:

```
$string = '{{ module:projects,id=1 }}';
$string = preg_replace('/{{ module:([^,]+),id=([0-9]+) }}/', 'include(\'$1.php?id=$2\')', $string);
// $string == include('projects.php?id=1')
```

Note: you can't actually include files with query strings on the end. PHP looks for file named 'projects.php?id=1'.

To get the file and actually include it:

```
preg_match_all('/{{ module:([^,]+),id=([0-9]+) }}/', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $filename) {
    // set $id before including the file. you could optionally set $_GET['id'].
    $id = $matches[2][$key];
    include($filename . '.php');
}
```

To support multiple parameters. Similar to Matmarbon's, but is more compact, doesn't assume parameter values will conform to \w, doesn't escape values, but also has less room for variations in spacing (/s*).

```
preg_match_all('/{{ module:([^,]+)((,[^=]+=[^,}]+)*) }}/', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $filename) {
    foreach (explode(',', trim($matches[2][$key], ', ')) as $vars) {
        list($k, $v) = explode('=', $vars);
        $_GET[$k] = $v;
    }
    // then this:
    include($filename . '.php');
    // or, to replace content:
    ob_start();
    include($filename . '.php');
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $string = str_replace($matches[0][$key], $contents, $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that using `preg_match` but to avoid the headache of creating the rule, I'd use `explode()` to cut out the different parts of the string.

Cut the string in this order:

1. `explode($string, "{{")` and fetch the 2nd element in the array (`$array[1]`)
2. `explode($result, "}}")` and fetch the 1st element
3. `explode($result, ":")` and fetch the 2nd element
4. `explode($result, ",")` and fetch both elements

Then you can use

```
$page = $result[0] . '.php';
$info = $result[1];
```

Then use `include($page.$info);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to look, if theres a repeating pattern in your string.
There are several ways to cut off your string and put it in another shape.

Cleanest approach would be to create a regular expression, then use this e.g. with [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

- Are you aware that `include('projects.php?id=1');` will include a file named `projects.php?id=1` and not `projects.php` ?
  To include `projects.php` and set `$_GET['id']` to `1` just do so:

  ```php
  $_GET['id'] = 1;
  include( 'projects.php' );
  ```
- You shoud the take a look at [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php). An example (assumed you know what you're doing about the parameters):

  ```php
  echo preg_replace( '/\\{\\{\\s*module:(\w+)(,(\w+=\w+))?\\s*\\}\\}/',
          'include(\'\\1?\\3\');',
          'bla bla bla bla {{ module:projects,id=1 }} bla bla bla bla' );
  ```

  Otherwise if my assumption about your parameters and the rest are correct here my solution:

  ```php
  function replace_modules( $var ){
      $stringparams = array_filter( explode( ',', substr( $var[2], 1 ) ) );
      $getparams = array();
      foreach($stringparams as $stringparam){
          list( $key, $value ) = explode( '=', $stringparam );
          $getparams[] = sprintf('$_GET[\'%s\']=\'%s\';',
              addslashes( $key ),
              addslashes( $value ) );
      }
      return sprintf( '<?php %sinclude(\'%s\') ?>',
          implode( $getparams ), addslashes($var[1]) );
  }

  $a= preg_replace_callback( '/\\{\\{\\s*module:(\w+)((,\w+=\w+)*)\\s*\\}\\}/',
      'replace_modules',
      'bla bla bla bla {{ module:projects,id=1,test=hello }} bla bla bla bla' );
  ```

  EDIT:
  Okay, now I think I know what you want; here it is:

  ```php
  function replace_modules( $var ){
      $stringparams = array_filter( explode( ',', substr( $var[2], 1 ) ) );
      foreach( $stringparams as $stringparam ){
          list( $key, $value ) = explode( '=', $stringparam );
          $_GET[$key] = $value;
      }
      ob_start();
      include( $var[1].'.php' );
      return ob_end_clean();
  }

  $a= preg_replace_callback( '/{{\\s*module:([^,]+)((,[^,=]+=[^,]*)*)\\s*}}/',
      'replace_modules',
      'bla bla bla bla {{ module:projects,id=1,test=hello }} bla bla bla bla' );
  ```

Comment: hey sorry i dont think i know what im doing with the params and TGIF cause i think im making this out harder than it is.  i have my string of bla bla bla {{projects,1}} bla bla bla i have a a projects.php where i want to print the id of 1 in so i want to take bla bla bla {{ projects,1}} bla bla bla and make it actually print bla bla bla 1 bla bla bla because somehow i included proejcts.php which printed the 1 in the middle of the string for me